# Data Not Retrieve in power query excel 2013?

Tags: excel, powerquery, powerpivot

I am creating a Calendar MS Excel 2013 through Power Query the other table data not shown in the workbook because I create a connection model and the data exist in data model so I am creating a blank query to and paste this power query to create a calendar please guide me where I am wrong
Thanks

> let Source =
>   {Number.From(List.Min(Excel[Date]))..Number.From(List.Max(Excel[Date]))},
>   "Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source,
>   Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error), "Renamed
>   Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Converted to Table",{{"Column1",
>   "Date"}}), "Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed
>   Columns",{{"Date", type date}}), "Added Custom" =
>   Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Year", each Date.Year([Date])),
>   "Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom",{{"Year",
>   Int64.Type}}), "Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type1",
>   "Month", each Date.Month([Date])), "Changed Type2" =
>   Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom1",{{"Month", Int64.Type}}),
>   "Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type2", "MonthName", each
>   Date.MonthName([Date])), "Changed Type3" =
>   Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom2",{{"MonthName", type
>   text}}), "Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type3",{{"Date",
>   Order.Ascending}}) in "Sorted Rows"

Comment: i got this error
Expression.Error: The name 'Excel' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's spelled correctly.

Comment: I think the reason  is, that you want to get data from a table (of query step) thats named Excel in: „ {Number.From(List.Min(Excel[Date]))..Number.From(List.Max(Excel[Date]))}“, but this table does Not exists.